# Are dimensions device independent pixels in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I am using Qt 5.6.2

If I am doing this:

```
Item {
   width: 20
   height: 20
}
```

Are the values for `width` and `height` device independent or exact pixels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, it is *device-dependent pixels*. What is an exact pixel on a monitor where you don't use the maximum resolution?

There are cases where it is not.
For example, that is the case if you use `scale` or where you rely on high DPI scaling. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html

One of the main reasons for having `real` values rather than `int`-values is that it reduces the amount of rounding-up/rounding-down errors, when wanting a size to be a fraction of another size.

See the comment on anchors:

> `anchors.alignWhenCentered (default true)` forces centered anchors to align to a whole pixel; if the item being centered has an odd width or height, the item will be positioned on a whole pixel rather than being placed on a half-pixel. This ensures the item is painted crisply. There are cases where this is not desirable; for example, when rotating the item, aliasing may be apparent as the center is rounded.

Getting device-independent sizes is hard, as the `Screen.devicePixelRatio` is exactly as stated in the documentation:

> The ratio between physical pixels and device-independent pixels for the screen.
> Common values are **1.0 on normal displays and 2.0 on Apple "retina" displays.**
> This QML property was introduced in Qt 5.4.

So, they don't care whether you have a 4K smartphone or an 800x600 CRT.

The `Screen.pixelDensity` might be more helpful, but I think it relies on OS/Hardware information. In my experience, it was correct often, but way off sometimes.